# Stop loss not triggering till next candle

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5

Not really sure why but when i use "stop" instead of "loss" in strategy.exit() my stop loss doesn't trigger on the same candle as the entry.

```
longCondition = DIPlus > DIMinus 

initialEntryPrice = strategy.position_avg_price
stoplosslong = initialEntryPrice - 2
stoplossshort = initialEntryPrice + 2

if (longCondition and buy and buy3 and buy5 and timeIsAllowed)
    strategy.entry("ENTER BUY", strategy.long)
    alert('6247349125333,buy,' +syminfo.ticker+ ',sl=8,tp=4,risk=100', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    
strategy.exit("EXIT BUY", profit= 4, stop = stoplosslong)

shortCondition = DIPlus  < DIMinus
if (shortCondition and sell and sell3 and sell5 and timeIsAllowed)
    strategy.entry("ENTER SELL", strategy.short)
    alert('6247349125333,sell,' +syminfo.ticker+ ',sl=8,tp=4,risk=100', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    
strategy.exit("EXIT SELL", profit=4, stop = stoplossshort)
```

Answer (score 1):

During backtesting strategy calculates on the `close` of each bar.

For the script

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script", overlay = true)

strategy.entry("ENTER BUY", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("EXIT BUY", stop = strategy.position_avg_price)
```

those 2 commands will be executed at `close` of the bar #0.
The entry will be placed only on the `open` of the next bar. At the `close` of the bar #0 the `strategy.exit()` command will be ignored, because at this moment `strategy.position_avg_price = na` (position is not opened yet).

After order placement at the `open` of the bar #1, again, strategy will be recalculated on the close of this bar, and as the `strategy.exit()` command will have finite value of the `stop` parameter, exit command will be placed and executed after bar #1.

When you use `loss` parameter, it has finite value, `strategy.exit()` executes on the `close` of the bar #0 and waiting for the `"ENTER BUY"` position to be opened, and, after position is filled, the command to exit position might exit position immediately after `loss` in ticks in reached.

If you want case 1 to work more like as case 2, you may enable `calc_on_order_fills` to execute `strategy.exit()` after "ENTER BUY" is opened.